# How to add the 'exact' prop in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to figure out how to add the `exact` property to the root link in a dynamically loaded menu. The menu entries are loaded from a REST API.

Currently the root path is always matched since it does not contain the `exact` property. In similar examples the root link is hard coded which I want to avoid.

This is the route that should be matched exactly

```
{ path: '/', component: HomePage }
```

The router-link is part of the menu, which is loaded via axios from the REST API and mapped to the state, including the root link "/". How can I access only this one item in the for loop to add the `exact` property?

```
  <router-link tag="li" class="link" v-for="item in menu" v-bind:key="item.id" :to="item.slug">{{ item.content }}</router-link>
```

May be I am missing something, or there is a better way to achieve this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally bind the exact prop like this.

```
<router-link tag="li" class="link" v-for="item in menu" :key="item.id" :to="item.slug" :exact="item.slug === '/' ? true : false">
   {{ item.content }}
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try

```js
<router-link tag="li" class="link" v-for="item in menu" v-bind:key="item.id" :to="item.slug" v-bind={ "exact": item.slug === "/" ? true : false }>{{ item.content }}</router-link>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly  the evaluation  does not work in v-bind